# Where can I see the website processing time

Tags: cache, debugging, ee-debug-toolbar

Where can I see the website processing time, serverside?
I mean how much time it took to compile the site for delivery.

I installed the ee debug toolbar. But which of this data is it?
[image]

The reason I ask is because I wonder if its worth to cache the relatively small site or if the server processing time is neglectable.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the processing time is the "0.9711s" on this image.

But you can add this values to your template, if you want to. The [`{elapsed_time}`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#elapsed-time), the [`{total_queries}`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#total-queries), etc are all available as standard global variables.

For example, I usually add something like this to the footer of every page:

```
{if logged_in_group_id == 1 OR site_url == "http://dev.domain.com"}
    <div id="devbar" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; position: fixed; background: #FFE203; color: #000000; padding: 9px; font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:1.5; z-index: 10000">
        Queries: <strong>{total_queries}</strong><br>
        Elapsed Time: <strong>{elapsed_time}s</strong><br>
        Memory Used: <strong>{memory_usage}</strong><br>
        Debug Mode: <strong>{debug_mode}</strong><br>
        Gzip Mode: <strong>{gzip_mode}</strong><br>
        App build: <strong>{app_build}</strong><br>
        App version: <strong>{app_version}</strong>
    </div>
{/if}
```

The conditional checks for a administrator user or a development domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in as Admin, you can simply enable Output Profiler and Template Debugging. This will only appear for the Admin usergroup.

**To enable this:**
Go to Admin > System Administration > Output & Debugging.

Check Yes to Display Output Profiler, and Display Template Debugging.

(This also saves writing unnecessary code in your templates.)

Comment: Yeah, it saves writing in your templates, but the Output Profiler and the Template Debugger are, sometimes, too much information. I really think you should add your answer to mine. Feel free to do that!